# Implementing an API using cherrypy that needs - (dashes/hyphens) in parameter name

Tags: python, api, cherrypy

I try to implement an API following an existing API specification. As programming language I use Python and CherryPy.

The problem is that in the API specification some parameters contain "-". So for example my-parameter.

But in Python I can't write

```
@cherrypy.expose
class Session(object):
    @cherrypy.tools.accept(media='text/plain')
    def GET(self, my-parameter):
```

What can I do to implement this API?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it'd work if you use `**kwargs` and extract a key by name.

Comment: That is true. I tried it today: The good thing: It is a possibility. But, there are two downsides: On the one hand, you can't 'require' a parameter anymore. You need to handle the missing parameters by yourself. On the other hand, if the user passes no parameters at all, you need to write a new method to handle this, because a **kwargs method is not called in this case.

Comment: You could try to use a [`before_handler` hook](https://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/extend.html#hook-point) to convert names in `cherrypy.request.params` inplace

Comment: I tried it. You get the params as dictionary and you can change the dictionarry like you want. So I replaced my-parameter with my_parameter. But unfortunately it does not call my method with my_parameter as parameter afterwards.
Do you think a dispatcher would be another option?

Comment: Maybe, or try some earlier hook to modify the URL, for example